# bcdboot "Failure when attempting to copy boot files" when attempting to install Windows on external hard drive

Tags: bootcamp, windows

I'm installing Windows 10 on a external hard drive using a 2015 MacBook following these instructions:

[Is it possible to use Boot Camp with Windows 10 from an external HDD?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/218105/is-it-possible-to-use-boot-camp-with-windows-10-from-an-external-hdd/267897#267897)

When running the ‘bcdboot’ command, I get the following

> Failure when attempting to copy boot files.