# Can I boot my mac from my old windows hard disk?

Tags: bootcamp, windows, external-disk

Recently, my old windows computer broke down and I decided to purchase a Mac to replace it , and so far, it has been great!

I have thought about using bootcamp to install windows on the mac as well, as I need several windows specific programs for my college work.

Rather than installing through bootcamp, I was wondering if it is possible for me to buy an external hard drive enclosure, place in my old windows hard disk (which has been reset and only contains a fresh windows 10 install) and boot my mac from that?

If possible, is there a way for me to get the Apple Windows Support Software separately in order to install all the required drivers on the windows disk?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible.  Windows is not natively capable of being moved from machine to machine in that manner.  You could install a fresh copy of Windows on external media and copy all of your old files over.  Its time consuming but here is a link to some instructions regarding how you can accomplish this.
[Is it possible to use Boot Camp with Windows 10 from an external HDD?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/218105/is-it-possible-to-use-boot-camp-with-windows-10-from-an-external-hdd)