# Is it possible to install 2 windows under 1 mac?

Tags: bootcamp, windows, ms-office, dual-boot

I don't want to use virtual machine software because of performance issues.

So I want to use Mac and has Mac OS. And from time to time use Windows, but I want to install 2 Windows (because I need to use 2 versions of Microsoft Office).

Does anyone know if it is possible with Boot Camp? Is there any other solution?

I am considering buying the newest Mac Pro with 512 GB of internal storage.

PS: I don't need to run these OS simultaneously, `Mac == restart ==> Windows 1 ==> restart ==> Windows 2 ==> Mac` will be fine.

Comment: It is possible.  You will have to manually do it, but I am genuinely curios about what performance issues you could possibly (perceive to) have.

Comment: Please see my update...

Comment: What version of Windows do you want to run? Also, what is the model/year of your Mac?

Comment: I am considering buying the newest Mac Pro, and I want to run 2 Windows 10...

Comment: Your question sounded simple until you posted "newest Mac Pro". I assume this model comes with one small internal disk and all other disks are connected externally. Is this so? You are aware that the Windows installer will not permit the installation of Windows on external disks.

Comment: I ask because of a similar question posted here: [How Do I Install Windows 10 To An External SSD Drive Under My Particular Config?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/307170/how-do-i-install-windows-10-to-an-external-ssd-drive-under-my-particular-config)

Comment: @DavidAnderson will not the 512GB internal disk be enough?

Comment: I assume both versions of Office require Windows? You can not use any Mac versions of Office?

Comment: @DavidAnderson for example Excel for Mac and Excel for Windows are quite different... I need to use Office for Windows...

Comment: @Allan Yes, when we run VM, Mac and Windows still share memory and CPU, right? I think dual-boot will allow Windows to benefit 100% from the resource.

Comment: I run an iMac with an i7 and 32GB of RAM.  I run 4 VMs, two of them being macOS Sierra for testing and Windows 10.  Other than sound being choppy, I have yet to see "performance issues."

Comment: @Allan What VM software do you use?

Comment: VirtualBox.  My other two machines are BSD based - one is a dev server running an AMP stack and the other is a Plex server that does on the fly video transcoding when watching movies.

Comment: Which versions of Office do you need to access? Except for a few restrictions, you should be able to install Office 2010, 2013, and 2016 simultaneously according to [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Install-and-use-different-versions-of-Office-on-the-same-PC-6ebb44ce-18a3-43f9-a187-b78c513788bf).

Comment: @PseudoSu is it possible to install office 2016 in english and office 2016 in chinese simultaneously?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is Yes, you can install macOS and two copies of Windows 10. They can  all be on the internal disk, but that might be a little tight with only 512 GB. This would not leave much space for your own files. I suppose if you ran out of internal space, you could add an external disk for your additional personal files. Apple's macOS can fairly easily installed on any combination of internal and/or external disks. Windows installation can vary from simple to extremely complicated.

Installing one copy of macOS followed by a single copy of Windows 10 on the first internal disk is fairly simple. Once macOS is installed, the Boot Camp Assistant can setup everything for Windows and the pass the installation to the Windows installer to complete the task.

Putting two copies of Windows on the internal disk would result in the ***partial*** loss of the use of the Boot Camp Assistant. You would use the Boot Camp Assistant, followed by the Windows installer, to install the first copy of Windows 10. You would be unable to use the Boot Camp Assistant to install the second copy of Windows. This would require you to manually partition the drive. There also would be some copying of files to their initial locations. The good news is that the Windows installer can still be used to install the second copy. The procedure for the second copy would be similar to the [answer to this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/306892/how-to-install-windows-10-into-a-2013-imac-without-using-the-boot-camp-assistant/307469#307469). The necessary changes to the procedure are itemized below.

- In step 11, choose the "Recovery" partition with the lowest number..
- Before executing step 14, any "MSR (Reserved)" type partitions that exist **after** the "WINSTALL" partition need to be deleted. The image below is an example of such a case.

[image: d3]

- In step 20, choose the "BOOTCAMP" volume with the drive letter (Ltr) `C`.

With external installations of Windows, you loose the use of the Boot Camp Assistant and the Windows installer. You end up typing in all the commands needed to install Windows. In other words, you can run windows from external disks, you just can not use the graphical Windows installer to help you do so. An example, of one such install procedure, is given [at this link](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/218105/is-it-possible-to-use-boot-camp-with-windows-10-from-an-external-hdd/307931#307931).

Comment: I don't need to install many software in my OSs... So why will 512GB be a little tight? Which OS will require disk space?

Comment: I updated my answer to address your questions.

Comment: I added the changes to the procedure to add a second Windows 10 to an internal disk. I could add more to step 2, but I first would have to know more about how your Mac is partitioned.