# How to install Windows on USB drive on MacBook?

Tags: macbook-pro, bootcamp, windows

The hard drive in my MacBook has only 128Gb of space. I therefore wanted to install Windows on an USB drive. The Windows installer doesn't allow me to select the USB drive however. Questioning the internet it seems to simply be that way. There was some Media Creation Tool mentioned somewhere to create a Windows USB drive, but that requires Windows to use.

Is my only hope therefore to find a Windows Computer to create my Windows USB drive? Or is there some way to install Windows on an USB drive with my MacBook?

Comment: @Monomeeth: I agree this is a duplicate question, but.... 1) You chose an question with not accepted answer. 2) The question is 6 1/2 years old. A lot has changed since then. 3) There are newer answers with must higher up votes than 26. 4) The answer with the most up votes is just a link to another web site. 5) There are other questions with accepted answers. This is just another example where users who do not have experience with a problem prefer to just mark any other question as the duplicate.

Comment: @DavidAnderson I appreciate the feedback. I must admit I didn't look at this too closely, only doing a quick check to see if there were newer questions that were a better fit (I didn't find any, but I admit the search functionality here isn't that great). Can you refer me to the newer answers with higher votes? I'd be more than happy to undo this and close it as a duplicate of that instead. Also, feel free to let me know if there are others you feel should be closed as duplicates of the question you nominate. Once again, appreciate the feedback! :)

Comment: @Monomeeth: I know of this question: [Is it possible to use Boot Camp with Windows 10 from an external HDD?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/218105/is-it-possible-to-use-boot-camp-with-windows-10-from-an-external-hdd) Still, the answers seem to be a bit stale. Apparently, third party products such as WinToUSB have since become available. This product has a nice GUI and does not require using the CLI. It is a shame current answers to this question will no longer be allowed here a AD.

Comment: @DavidAnderson I've reclosed this as a duplicate of the question you nominated. Can I ask you to clarify what you meant by *"It is a shame current answers to this question will no longer be allowed here a AD"*?