# Drivers not working on Windows 10 installed (CLI process) on external SSD running on Mac mini - EFI Started But Screen Black After Win Logo

Tags: bootcamp, windows, startup

I followed the steps listed in https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/384447/9058 to install Windows 10 via CLI but am stuck at step 7.

I restarted my Mac Mini and held down the option key. The Mac HD and and EFI HD came up. I clicked on the EFI. The Windows Logo or insignia (the little boxes)came up and it looked like all was well for about a minute or so and then the screen goes black. The Mac Mini remains on but the screen is blank.

How can I proceed from here?

The following is a picture of my screen in Windows Terminal

Almost to the end but stuck over the $WinPEDriver$

[image]

Oh well, it was an adventure typing inside the terminal or CLI.

How do I continue from here? Thanks!

### Update 1

Dear David, Here is a picture of my Terminal. It seems the last command wasn't accepted.

[image]

### Update 2

Dear David,

I tried these new commands but as you can see, they didn't produce the results we were hoping for.

[image]

Where do I go from here? Thanks!

### Update 3

Good Evening David, Here is a picture of the results of latest command.

[image]

Thanks!

### Update 4

Good Evening David, F10 not working once I reach the screen below.

[image]

You mentioned it may be a driver issue that is not loading. Below is a picture of WINSTALL listing.

[image]

What steps should I take from here? Thanks!

### Update 5

I successfully copied the 2 individual folders inside of Windows Support folder to WINSTALL drive as seen below.

[image]

It worked!!! Below is a picture of Apple Update in process!

[image]

I can't begin to express my gratitude for working so patiently and consistently with me. Below is the finished product. Windows running on my Samsung 500GB drive.

[image]

I made the mistake of purchasing my Mac Mini without enough storage. I thought I could add more later. As you probably know, the storage is soldered in and adding more is not possible. An external drive is necessary. I started 2 months ago with Jeff at 9 to 5 Mac on YTube. Then it was Chris K's YT channel. Thank goodness I stumbled onto your website here at Stack Exchange. I realize you will have to edit these comments but I wanted you to know what a tremendous service you provide. Thanks!!!!

Comment: @DavidAnderson The OP was refering to another post of yours :-)

Comment: Andrew, are you sure it's not just the screen saver kicking in a after a minute?

Comment: I don't think so, but I will give that a try and see if that is the case. Thanks!

Comment: I have a 2018 Mac Mini 8 GB with USB Apple keyboard and logicteck M100 USB mouse.  I also have a 1 TB USB external HDD. I will try the procedure and report back if I have the same problem.

Comment: Dear Nohillside, that was it! Screensaver. My dad always said,"try the easy fixes first." Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to recreate the problem shown in the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rm0I7.jpg) you posted. Apparently, at least the driver for the internal drive has to be loaded from the `WINSTALL` volume before the `dism` command will work properly. I update the instructions so you will proceed with the GUI steps for installation until the window below appears.

[image]

At this point, the drivers have loaded, so you can proceed and open a Command Prompt window and start entering commands.

I changed the examples in my answer to be from an actually installation of Windows 10 (1909) on to a external HDD connected to a 2018 Mac mini. I also changes some of the steps, so you should thoroughly review the answer before proceeding.

Let me know, if you have any other problems.

### Update 1

The image you posted was a bit blurry. A far as I can see, you did type the following command in correctly.

```
chflags nohidden /Volumes/WINSTALL/label/.d*
```

However, I believe you had pathname expansion disabled. This would cause the error message shown in the image. I replaced the command with two commands, that do not require pathname expansion.

I should note that according to the history, you entered the command give below, which should have produced an error message.

```
bless --folder/Volumes/WINSTALL/label --label "Windows"
```

You should have typed the command given below.

```
bless --folder /Volumes/WINSTALL/label --label "Windows"
```

This command would have produced the following files.

```
/Volumes/WINSTALL/label/.disk_label
/Volumes/WINSTALL/label/.disk_label_2x
```

If these files do not exist, then the new commands given below would fail.

```
chflags nohidden /Volumes/WINSTALL/label/.disk_label
chflags nohidden /Volumes/WINSTALL/label/.disk_label_2x
```

### Update 2

Your "Update 2" given no indication that a failure occurred. In other words, the image shows that the command appeared to work correctly. However, since the `chflags` command is causing problems for you, I decided to remove the the use of the `chflags` entirely from my answer. Instead, I added the following Windows command to step 8.

```
attrib -h t:\label\*
```

### Update 3

The command `attrib` is a part of Windows. The command works when entered in a Microsoft Command Prompt window. The command will not work in a Apple macOS Terminal application window. You do not have to enter the attrib command until step 8. During step 8, you will have a Command Prompt window open.

### Update 4

To open a Command Prompt window, you are suppose to press the <kbd>shift</kbd> and <kbd>F10</kbd> keys at the same time.

You copied the `WindowsSupport` folder to the `WINSTALL` volume. The instructions in step 4 stated to *copy **the contents of** the `WindowsSupport` folder to the `WINSTALL` volume*. The `$WinPEDriver$` and `BootCamp` folder should appear in the root folder of the `WINSTALL` volume, as shown below.

[image]

### Update 5

I am glad to see you have successfully installed Windows 10. If you feel my answer solved your problem, then I would ask you to accept my answer. This will place a green checkmark next to this answer. This helps other users identify that a solution was found.

Comment: Thank you David! I will let you know how it works.

Comment: @AndrewW: I updated my answer.

Comment: Sorry about the blurriness of the picture. I am taking it from my MacBook Pro using Photo Booth.

Comment: Thank you for the update. I will let you know how it works.

Comment: Thanks David!  I will apply the most recent command and let you know my results.

Comment: Good Morning David, I will copy the contents of the Window Support folder not the folder itself. Thanks!

Comment: How do I accept your answer? I don't see an icon that states acceptance.

Comment: @AndrewW: Look for the [gray checkmark](https://imgur.com/OUIYQZD) to the left of my answer. Click on the checkmark and it should turn green.

Comment: If there's anything else I can do, please let me know. Thanks David! By the way, I successfully removed the installation partition via Command Prompt.

Comment: You can up vote by clicking on the up arrow. You may have done this already. I have no way to knowing.

Comment: Would it be appropriate to link this page to Chris K's YouTube channel?

Comment: What do you mean David, "make an edit."

Comment: Users often add links to YouTube, so I think it would be OK to link this page to Chris K's YouTube channel. I moved your reference to Chris K's YouTube channel to Update 5 of your question. You might also want to put a link in your answer to to Chris K's YouTube video.

Comment: Okay, will do. I am seeking permission from Chris K. before I make the link.