# Windows installation through the Boot Camp Assistant and SSD error

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, windows, bootcamp, ssd

I have a MacBook Pro 2017, and I've been trying to install Windows 10 on it for quite a while through the Boot Camp Assistant, but I was advised to purchase an SSD (Samsung T7 500 GB).

However, that also did not solve my issue. Every time I try to install Windows, the first time the Mac boots from the external startup disk, I am faced with a BSOD error saying 'your computer ran into an error, please restart'.

I have tried multiple Windows 10 ISO's 1909, 1809, 1607, and the current version 20H2 available on Microsoft (30th October 2020). I also reset PRAM before every installation.

To install Windows, I followed this [9to5Mac tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3IhW722IMwE), as well as the accepted answer to this [question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/384355/drivers-not-working-on-windows-10-installed-cli-process-on-external-ssd-runnin).

Comment: The Samsung T7 is USB 3.2 drive. Did Boot Camp Assistant allow you to install to this drive? If so, the did the Windows GUI allow you to select a partition on this drive? Did you try installing Windows to the internal drive? Have you considered using a more expansive but faster thunderbolt 3 drive such as the Samsung X5?

Comment: Hey im not sure on what you meant by if BCA allowed me to install on the drive? i followed the 9to5 mac tutorial as well as this method to try install windows https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/384355/drivers-not-working-on-windows-10-installed-cli-process-on-external-ssd-runnin. I did try installing windows on the internal drive and had the same issue where I got a blue screen telling me your 'pc ran into a problem and needs to restart' and either booted back into mac os or stuck in an infinite loop with that error

Comment: Did you try [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/384355/drivers-not-working-on-windows-10-installed-cli-process-on-external-ssd-runnin/384447#384447)? I realize you do not have a T2 chip, so you can ignore that part of the answer. How about any of the answers to [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/218105/is-it-possible-to-use-boot-camp-with-windows-10-from-an-external-hdd)? Can you provide a link to the 9to5 mac tutorial you have referred to?

Comment: Did the BSOD occur before or after the installation of the Windows Support Software from Apple?

Comment: @DavidAnderson yes I've tried that method, however, I have not tried any of the methods shown in the second link, which out of them do you think is the most appropriate. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3IhW722IMwE&t=716s Thats the Guide I followed.

Comment: @DavidAnderson the error happens at this point (https://youtu.be/3IhW722IMwE?t=833) when I switch to the windows gui for installation.

Answer (score 0):

At time mark 11:49 in the 9to5Mac video the author is about to turn off the virtual machine. However, before turning off, a command needs to be entered to copy the drivers from the `$WinPEDriver$` folder to the drivers store on the USB drive. This can be accomplished by executing the following steps.

> Note: You an enlarge an image by either clicking on the image or opening in a new window.

1. From the Start Menu, open a `Command Prompt` window by selecting `Run as administrator`, as shown below.

   [image]

   When the popup windows shown below appears, click on the `Yes` button.

   [image]
2. In the Command Prompt window, enter the following command, as shown in the image below. The external USB drive letter in the video was `F`. If your external USB drive has been assigned a different letter, then make the appropriate substitutions when entering the command shown below.

   ```
   dism /Image:F:\ /Add-Driver /Driver:F:\WindowsSupport\$WinPEDriver$ /Recurse /ForceUnsigned
   ```

   [image]

   > Note: Some drivers are not meant to be installed this way. If such a driver is encountered, then you may see a warning message. You can ignore these messages.
3. When the `dism` command is finished, you can enter the `exit` command to close the Command Prompt window.
4. Proceed with the instructions given in the video.

Comment: Arnav: If this does not fix your problem, then I wonder if you have the correct Windows Support Software.

Comment: Oh well i have tried this and unfortunately it does not work too, I've re installed the windows support software and still no luck, My next option is to downgrade the OS and then try