# How to update a MacOS installed in an external SSD beyond Sierra

Tags: macbook-pro, bootcamp, ssd, software-update

My 2015 MacBook Pro 13's internal SSD died during an update yesterday. When I try booting it says there are no drives to boot from. I used Internet Recovery and there is no sign of the internal SSD anywhere.

So, I plugged in a brand new 1 TB external SSD, it installed El Capitan and it worked perfectly. I updated it to Sierra without issues but when I try to update it further to High Sierra and beyond I get a message saying the disk doesn't have a firmware partition. I google this issue and it seems that MacOS versions released after Sierra require a working internal storage disk in order to install. Is it possible install the High Sierra in a USB stick and use that to run the installer?

Edit: It was running Mojave when it died, I had noticed that it was running much slower than usual which is why I tried updating it.

I was also wondering if it is possible to install Windows 10 in a different partition of the same external SSD since the stuff I need for work runs on it, however I can't get bootcamp to work without a internal SSD either.

Comment: It might be helpful to include a link to that info you found along with a relevant quote from that page. It would be helpful in troubleshooting your issue.

Comment: Which version of macOS was on the drive that died?

Comment: Hmm. That is interesting. The T2 chip isn't getting in your way. I usually just replace the SSD in the laptop myself because it's not that hard (replacing it in iMac is another ball of wax).

Answer (score 1):

Below are some possible solutions.

- Replace the internal drive. This [website](https://eshop.macsales.com/shop/ssd/owc/macbook-pro-retina-display/2013-2014-2015) shows replacement drives and links to installation videos.
- Use another Mac with a working internal drive to upgrade the external drive to High Sierra or Mojave. Once completed, you Mac should boot from the upgraded external drive.
- Try upgrading directly to Mojave, thus bypassing High Sierra.
- Use an virtual machine to update to High Sierra. Here, the virtual machine would have a virtual internal and a physical external drive. Once the upgrade is complete, you should be able to boot from the upgrading external drive using the physical Mac.
- Many answers explaining how to install Windows 10 on a external drive have been posted here at Ask Different. You could start with [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/384355/drivers-not-working-on-windows-10-installed-cli-process-on-external-ssd-runnin/384447#384447). Since you have El Capitan installed on the external drive, you probably will have to adapt an existing answer.