# Installing BootCamp on a Late 2014 iMac

Tags: hard-drive, windows, bootcamp, imac, parallels-desktop

I'm trying to install Windows via BootCamp on a Late 2014 iMac, so far to no avail.

## First attempts, to external drive

First I attempted to install it to an external drive.

I already have a working installation on Parallels, which I thought it could have helped, but it didn't.

Simply using WinToUsb from Parallels to the target drive created a drive which booted into blue Recovery (With error `0xC0000225` unless I'm mistaken).

I've tried many variations of guides I found online, but none worked.

VirtualBox simply refused to start the image, claiming the kernel drivers weren't installed (that's a lie, they were – any suggestion on approving them manually has failed too).

## Further attempts, giving up and installing to the main drive

Even installing to the main drive has failed.

BootCamp wants to create a bootable windows image on a blank external drive first, but then it fails to do so with a super generic error.

I've tried two different Windows ISOs, both downloaded from Microsoft site (one today, the other one several months ago).

Some clueless guide generically suggests to "update MacOS", but that's not possible: I'm on Big Sur, and cannot upgrade to Monterey since it's not supported for my model.

---

Right now I'm completely stuck and I have exactly zero clue on how to proceed.

Comment: Is your question about installing to the internal or external drive? What is the name of the Windows ISO you intend to use?

Comment: External is preferred, but at this point anything would do. I'll grab the name of the iso when I'm back home

Comment: @DavidAnderson the ISOs I tried were `Win10_21H2_EnglishInternational_x64.iso` (downloaded yesterday), and `Win10_1909_EnglishInternational_x64.iso` (possibly from April 2020).

Comment: Your question was asked and answered many year ago. See [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/218105/is-it-possible-to-use-boot-camp-with-windows-10-from-an-external-hdd). Have you tried any of the given answers?

Comment: @DavidAnderson _"VirtualBox simply refused to start the image, claiming the kernel drivers weren't installed (that's a lie, they were – any suggestion on approving them manually has failed too)."_

Comment: The last time I can remember posting instructions for installing Windows 10 on an external drive was March 2020. See [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/384355/drivers-not-working-on-windows-10-installed-cli-process-on-external-ssd-runnin/384447#384447). You can ignore the part about the T2 chip. This answer does not use VirtualBox.

Comment: @DavidAnderson yeah, unfortunately one of the problems with that post is that now Boot Camp Assistant is no longer able to download the "Windows support software", it just hangs at the very beginning…

Comment: You can download the Window Support Software without using the Boot Camp Assistant. I just did for a `iMac15,1`. The link is [http://swcdn.apple.com/content/downloads/62/58/041-98143-A_HN8B941A1T/nknv1gt3xcgylggwc11kl5e0j4296tjfo1/BootCampESD.pkg](http://swcdn.apple.com/content/downloads/62/58/041-98143-A_HN8B941A1T/nknv1gt3xcgylggwc11kl5e0j4296tjfo1/BootCampESD.pkg).