iMac 2020 bootcamp mode boot failed with thunderbold connected disk
I followed a great link on how to make bootcamp on an external disk here https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/384447/588919
but I faced with several issues:

I tried to install Win 10 pro and Win 11 Pro on my external NVME disk
Win 11 seems to have a more smart installer - it can start installing via GUI but always gets an error on 82% (don't know what is going on at that stage)
if I apply images via DISM as described in the Link it finishes ok, but iMac can't boot due to BSOD - inaccessible boot device, no matter what Windows versions on W10 and W11 the issue is the same
I checked that TbtBusDrv.sys driver is added to the bootcamp disk and I modified HKLM/SYSTEM/ControlSet001/Services/nhi registry DWORD32 Start to 0x0000000 value (default was 0x00000003 ) to start it during the boot process but it does not help me

Do you have any Ideas on how to fix BSOD?


The answer was tested using an USB drive. The 2018 Mac mini does have an external 500 GB Samsung X5 Thunderbolt 3 SSD, but I never tried installing Windows to that drive.

Funny thing, since I tried first to install Windows 11, the GUI installer told me that it can't install windows 11 on USB disk, so I changed it to TBT3 nvme disk , but I didn't try to install it on USB disk via DISM, so let's see

update, on USB SSD disk Windows 11 pro works on iMac 2020
