# Install Windows 10 on external hard drive.. but

Tags: mac

i want to install windows 10 to my external disk drive on this early 2008 iMac, but when i follow some tutorials online, when booting to windows 10 setup i only get this message

"no bootable device found -- insert boot disk and press keys"

so i am in a loophole now.
please help me

Comment: Are you using a Windows 10 DVD to install or are you using some other method?

Comment: using the usb install

Comment: When you hold down the option key at startup with the Windows USB flash drive installer plugged in, you should boot to the Mac Startup Manager. What labels do you get for the external drive icons?

Comment: EFI Boot, but when booting it just say the error in my question, and i also tried using virtualisation when installing and it just "almost" corrupted my system when installing it to my external disk

Comment: The problem is that if you do not get the label "Windows" in the Startup Manager, then your Mac is an older model that can not BIOS boot from an external drive. The drivers provided by Apple for all 2008 Macs are designed for a BIOS booting Windows. You can try to install for a EFI boot on the external drive, but the drivers probably will not work correctly.

Comment: soooo, what will i do?

Comment: The other problem is your Mac only has USB 2.0 jacks. If you could get Windows 10 installed on an external drive, Windows would run to slow to be of any real use. You only practical option would be to install Windows to an internal drive.

Comment: im very patient and i have ran many things slower than this

Comment: Why not use an internal drive?

Comment: exchanged it for a ssd

Comment: i just want to install windows on it

Comment: I assume you have OS X (macOS) installed on the internal drive. If so, then the instructions for installing Windows 10 to EFI boot from an external drive are give as answers to the question: [Is it possible to use Boot Camp with Windows 10 from an external HDD?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/218105/is-it-possible-to-use-boot-camp-with-windows-10-from-an-external-hdd).

Comment: Which instructions there? There are many..

Comment: An answers can be ranked by votes. The answer with the highest votes is probably the best one to pick. However, I do have a preference for my answer.